# sys.exit(1) not working, the script ends with code 0

Tags: python, systemd

I have the following code:

```
try:
    self._collect_persons_status()
except manager.AsteriskManagerError:
    # If it is not possible to continue with the collection of initial
    # person statuses via Asterisk Manager, end the program with an
    # error code.
    logger.debug('*** exit with 1!!')
    sys.exit(1)
```

This script is handled via systemd (runs as a daemon with a loop).

From the log I can see that `*** exit with 1!!` is printed, but the script ends with code 0, not 1 as expected:

[image: script-exit-code]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you perhaps have `try: <invoke script entry point> except: <log error>` at the script top-level?

Comment: @user4815162342 oh yes, you're right! If you post this as an answer I'll give you the best check

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have something like this at script top-level, it will prevent `sys.exit()` from exiting the program:

```
try:
    <invoke script entry point>
except:
    <log the error>
```

This is because `sys.exit()` is implemented by raising the `SystemExit` exception. You can fix the code by changing `except:` to `except Exception` which won't catch `SystemExit` (and some other low-level exceptions that you probably don't want to handle either).

Comment: I would use `except Exception`, which will not catch exiting exceptions.

Comment: @timgeb Good idea; I've now amended the answer to recommend that instead of explicit `except SystemExit`.